# Automatic execution of a list of commands with every excution performed in a bash terminal

Tags: bash

I want a list of commands to be executed automatically every time a command is executed in a bash terminal.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Go read about the `DEBUG` trap. `trap 'echo foo; echo bar' DEBUG`.

Comment: no man page seems like a trap but ok

Comment: `help trap`. `man bash`, then search for `DEBUG.*trap`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a post-lude after each command, you need a `DEBUG` trap as mentioned in the comments. If you only need to execute commands once Bash prompts you back with `...$`, then you can use `PROMPT_COMMAND`

Append to any existing (probably none) `PROMPT_COMMAND`, taking care of newlines:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND%$'\n'}$'\nmyjunk'
```

Notes:

- the only safe way to append to a shell script (and `PROMPT_COMMAND` is a shell script) is by appending a newline first.
- Bash, ksh and zsh have a `$''` syntax which translates `\n` and other escapes. This is not POSIX-specified

Replace `myjunk` with `yourjunk`.

Comment: Note that interpreting the question _literally_ means they want to execute the list of commands twice if `ls; ls` is entered on the command line, and that they want to call it several times for `for name in *; do echo "$name"; done`.  This is why the comments on the question suggests  using a `DEBUG` trap.

Comment: Good point. I missed that